# jQuery slideDown() not working first time

Tags: jquery

Why does slideDown() not work the first time?

```
$('#lnkInfo').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).blur();
    if ($(this).text() == 'More info') {
        $('#spnMoreInfo').slideDown(200);
        $(this).text('Less info');
    }
    else if ($(this).text() == 'Less info') {
        $('#spnMoreInfo').slideUp(200);
        $(this).text('More info');
    }
});
```

[jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/RGwz6/)

**edit:** using Firefox 22.0

Comment: It is working fine for me :)

Comment: First time it just shows for me, doesn't slide down.

Comment: @user982119 Which browser you are using?

Comment: Working fine in firefox 22.0 too :)

Comment: Well, I can reproduce it in Firefox 22.

Comment: are you saying the first time you click it isn't sliding? it does for me.. that's as expected.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Change the `<span id="spnMoreInfo" ...>` to a `div`. jQuery can't figure out the height before showing it. This is why it displays instantly instead of sliding.

[Modified fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/RGwz6/11/).

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that you are using a `<span>` element that is an inline element. Try with a `<div>` and it will slide.